# SwingController get page coordinate

Tags: java, swing, icepdf

Using `IcePdf` (ver 1.8) i integrate a `SwingController` into my `JPanel` to use it in my application. Since the page displayed into the `SwingController` is in a specific position into the controller.
How can i obtain the coordinate of the page (top left corner for example, o bottom left if using PDF coordinate) relative to the whole `SwingController` so i can obtain the Page coordinate relative to the `JPanel` ?

I searched deep in the API of IcePDf but i cannot figure out how to do this. Thanks.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? I do not understand this "Page coordinate relative to the `JPanel`"...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
swingController.getDocumentViewController()
               .getDocumentView().getViewModel().getPageBounds(0).getLocation();
```